# Is it possible to a use guides in MS Office similar to Photoshop?

Tags: guides, microsoft-office

Is there a way to use guides in MS Office Word and PowerPoint as you can in Photoshop? I wish to do the same in Office for moving things at a certain distance as we do in Photoshop.

[image: guiding in photoshop]

Comment: good question if you explain more. u mean u could drag ruler as what we use in photoshop?

Comment: I think you may mean Guides. Anyways `View > Guides > Guides` and/or `View > Ruler`. Now if you right click an empty spot in the document, you can add a guide by choosing `Guides > Add Vertical guide`. If you right click one of the existing guides the options to add guides should be at the top of the context menu. This could be slightly different in other versions.

Comment: Word isn't designed to be used for layout. And PowerPoint just assumes some MBA is using it, not a designer.

Comment: Recipe for insanity:  Word + Layout.  Right there with you, @Metis  OTOH, while there are a few tricks to doing print layouts in PPT, it's a decent tool; doesn't have the typographical finesse that an InDesign or the like has, but if Office is what you have, PPT is the hammer of choice.

Comment: In PPT you can also rightclick the shape you want to move, choose Size & Position, then use the resulting dialog box or pane (depending on version) to specify the exact position you want.

Answer (score 2):

MS Office users can live without quides. They can switch on the grid that has easily customizable  horizontal and vertical spacings.

Alternatively they can easily draw colored lines that can be used as quides and deleted when not any more needed. This would be impractical in Photoshop because every line needs  a layer and some coloring, too.

In Office: Draw the line holding Shift =>you get exactly horizontal, vertical or 45 degrees tilted line as you want. Dragging a line holding Ctrl makes a copy.

If snap is on, the object you drag snaps to the line, if it gets near enough.

Comment: Why go through all that when guides are easily available in PowerPoint?  I don't know or care whether they're available in Word because I've tried to do layout in Word before and MUCH prefer root canals. ;-)

Comment: @SteveRindsberg Layout in Word goes well as soon as one doesn't try to apply the basic typewriting, only textboxes and other inserted objects. MS Publisher is like Word without the basic typewiting. A drawn line is not more complex than taking a quide.

Answer (score 1):

Both Powerpoint and Publisher allow you to use guides similar to those used in Photoshop, Illustrator or InDesign. I don't have Publisher on my computer, so I can't show you an example in Publisher, but in Powerpoint, you access the guides by going to the view menu, and on the "Show" portion of the ribbon, check the box that says guides.

[image]

The window now will show you two centered guides, one horizontal and one vertical.

[image]

You can add additional guides either using the method that @joonas mentions in the comments above, or by placing your cursor on top of one of the guides until it turns into a double-sided arrow, holding down the Ctrl key (for Windows-not sure the equivalent key on a Mac) and dragging the new guide where you want to put it. As you drag the new guide, it shows you the distance you have dragged it, so if you pay attention you can set up guides at specific intervals.  Not as simple as in the Adobe products, but it can be done.

In order to delete a guide, click and drag the guide off the edge of your powerpoint "page."  You will see the guide gradually fade away.

As I said, I don't have Publisher installed, and have tried to avoid using it whenever possible-but if I remember correctly, the guides work similarly to the way I have just described.

Unfortunately, Microsoft Word and Excel do not have any guides.